# QLibraryInfo doesn't seem to load qt.conf

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I jsut installed Qt 4.7.2 and I'm trying to use the `QLibraryInfo` class. My problem is that `QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PrefixPath)` always returns `C:\work3\qt-4.7-vs2010-x86` which doesn't exist on my generation machine (should be `C:\Qt\qt-4.7.2`).

According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qt-conf.html) I tried to create a `qt.conf` file  alongside my program, but the problem still remains. Here's its content:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=C:/Qt/qt-4.7.2/
```

For now I used a symlink to bypass the issue, but I'd like to know if there's a proper solution.
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here's the program using the `QLibraryInfo`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); //< added after Piotr's suggestion

    QFile outf("qtdirs.out");

    if (!outf.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Truncate|QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;

    QTextStream out(&outf);

    out << QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PrefixPath) << '\n';
    out << QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::HeadersPath) << '\n';

...
}
```

Comment: Did you build Qt 4.7.2 from sources or install binaries?

Comment: I installed the binaries available at  http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008

Comment: Do you use QLibraryInfo **after** creating QApplication/QCoreApplication?

Comment: No, the QApplication object is even never created. The only purpose of the application is to write the Qt paths to a file. It's one of the first steps of the configure script to build PyQt.

Comment: That's the problem. You need at least QCoreApplication for this to work.

Comment: I created a `QCoreApplication`, but it doesn't work better...

Comment: Can you post a minimal test case?

Comment: The edit I made in the original post isn't enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QCoreApplication must be created because that is how the QLibraryInfo is able to determine the application directory (`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`) from which to load the qt.conf file. Alternatively, the qt.conf can be built into the application as a resource with the path ":/qt/etc/qt.conf".

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, instantiating a `QCoreApplication` object doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Something else must be wrong. What is output if you add this to the bottom of the example? `out << QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() << '\n'; out << "qt.conf " << QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).exists("qt.conf") << '\n';`

Comment: My bad, I wasn't using the right exe. Adding the QCoreApplication is the right answer.